# eth_getLogs and some missing logs

Tags: go-ethereum, events

I have an indexing software that scans the blockchain for certain events. It works continuosly using eth_getLogs over my nodes.

It works perfectly, but I'm seeing that sometimes I'm missing some events that should be in eth_getLogs. If I replay the eth_geLogs query again, I can see the event perfectly, but in real time, very few times I miss some events.

I'm trying to understand what is happening. I'm doing something very similar to what thegraph does. I start at a certain blockNumber, scan a batch of logs looking for certain events and repeat it over and over. Once I'm fully synchronized (I'm on the last block and I'm in real time), make the same process every few seconds. I think that this is when it fails, because I've never seen the missing logs on past events, only in recent events.

I don't know if the cause is a chain reorganization or something like that and I don't know how can I assure I don't miss any event.

Comment: Maybe try The Graph Discord or Github?

Comment: To detect a chain reorg you can keep a map of recent block numbers to block hashes, if some of the block hashes have changed then you are sure it was a chain reorg.

Comment: @Soltrac Did you find the cause of this?

Comment: @GeorgeR., not really. I'm trying to detect chain reorgs, but it is difficult.

Comment: @Soltrac Got it, for now what I'm doing is always listening one block behind the head to make sure I'm not missing anything. This introduces a few seconds of delay but it's better than missing logs.